# Wordpress Menu limit problem - Can't save the menu if more than 41 items

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a Wordpress site which has about 160 items in the menu which was set up a few years ago. The problem is I can no longer edit it - when I try to add menu items and save it I get a Bad Request error. If I reduce the menu to 41 items or less the menu will save, 42 or more items and it will not. I am using a Max Mega Menu plugin which was provide reduced the number from the default 80.

Every time I search for a solution it always gives the answer to increase the max_input_vars in php.ini – the issue is this is already set to 5000, and increasing it further does not help at all with the menu length (41 is still the max).

The site is using Wordpress 6.2.2, I have tried revering to an older wordpress version, using the default wordpress theme, and deactivating all the plugins – none of this has an impact.

The site is hosted on cPanel and is running PHP 8.2 (older php versions, also makes no difference).

What could be limiting the menu length aside from max_input_vars?

Comment: Does submitting the form really send that much fields? What does the server's error log tell you about this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nico, I checked the server log and there was no errors!